# An error is reported when the SysIntegrity API of HMS Core Safety Detect is integrated

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

The following error information is displayed when I integrate the SysIntegrity API of HMS Core Safety Detect:

```
Failed to read meta data for the AppID. D/SafetyDetectRepositoryImpl: unknown status code: 907135000
```

My code is as follows:

```
SafetyDetect.getClient(getActivity())
            .sysIntegrity(nonce, APP_ID)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SysIntegrityResp>() {
          ...
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          ...
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Verify that android:name and android:appid in meta-data in the AndroidManifest.xml file are correctly configured. The value of android:appid should be the actual app ID.

Comment: A project using product flavors has more than one app_id. Would it be correct in this case to manually type app_id in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Currently,It is not recommended to add app Id to AndroidManifest .
In flavor scenarios, you can add a JSON file to the folder of each flavor to read the app ID,pls kindly refer this link: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Where in manifest I should place meta-data tag?

Answer (score 0):

1.Error code 907135000:Verify that related input parameters are correctly set, for example, appid in the manifest file and whether to use the certificate signature.

2.Checking Steps：
a. check agc plugin cofig: Must be added in application module as below
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
b. check json file dowloaded from agc and add in your proj as below
   [json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss0MX.png)